# Map a row index back to the original indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let us say I have a dataframe, and I want to find all negative values of a column, like this:

```
df_negAssets = df_original[df_original["assets"] < 0]
```

Now I have a new dataframe, out of my original indexed dataframe. This dataframe might contain 7 rows.

My question is: how do I map these 7 rows to the original dataframe?

```
df_negAssets.iloc(2)
```

gives me the third row. But which row in my original dataframe does it corresponds to? Is it row 59? How can I find out that index "2" in my view, corresponds to index "59" in my original dataframe? And how do I go back? "2" -> "59", and how to find out that "59" -> "2"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the mapping:

```
df_negAssets.index
```

*> How can I find out that index "2" in the new dataframe, corresponds to index "59" in my original dataframe?*

```
df_negAssets.index[2] == 59
```

*> And how do I go back? ... and how to find out that "59" -> "2"?*

```
numpy.where(df_negAssets.index == 59)[0][0] == 2
```

Are you sure you need to? Remember you can use `df_negAssets[59]`.

By the way, `df_negAssets` is not a view. It's a new DataFrame. If you take an entire column, or a slice (`df[0][x:y:z]`) then it can be a view. When you use a condition like `<0`, it creates a new DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected my post. I am not going to use this, but, out of curiosity, how do I map between slice and dataframe, in both directions? Is it tricky to do, then skip this question.